# application freezing while fetching data from angularjs ajax call

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to fetch data from angularjs $http service and in this service I am using two ajax call (these call affecting on the same page) but due to second call my application is freezing until I am not getting response from that call.

Here is My controller.js code:-

```
$q.all([
            //first ajax call   
            $http({     
                    method:"post",
                    url:"/catalog.php",  //From here I am fetching one kind of data that I have to show on main page
                    data:parameter,                         
                    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}                     
                }).success(function(data){                              

                    //some conditions to show main page data                                
                    //from here I am showing the content to main page           

                }),     
            ,
        ]).then(function(){                     

                        $timeout(function(){                        

                            //this is the second ajax call to get the another part of data                                  
                            $http({                         
                                    url:"/filter.php",      //second ajax call to get right side filter section data                    
                                    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}                     
                                }).success(function(data){   

                                    //From here I am creating another div on the same page (Large data on the right side of the page)   
                                    //Due to this call my application is getting hanged until the response is completed



                                });                             

                        },100);                                                             

                });
```

I want my application shouldn't freeze due to second ajax call, while its running after the first ajax call. Right now the second ajax call freezing my application.

Comment: Are you feeding the second call's response to ng-repeat? If it's a lot of data and/or with directives on each ng-repeat's iteration, the browser will freeze until complete.

Comment: Yes I am creating the big html by using ng-repeat from the response of second ajax call. How can I solve this problem, as i have to show that data also on the same page while i have to maintain the speed as well, that's why I was simply calling the first ajax call so that user can see the data after then i am calling the second ajax call, so that in background I can create another part of html using second ajax call response.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the **dev tool**s (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) in your browser to see what's happening.

Open the **Network tab**. Your http calls should be there.

You can also open the **Timeline tab** to see what part of the call is taking so long.

Taking into account that you are loading a lot of data, I would recommend to use infinite scroll https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

This just loads the visible part of your ng-repeat and then loads more data, if you scroll down.

Comment: Thanks Lisa, but I am not loading that data in main content. I am creating another html on the same page like menu filter on right side (As we see usually filter on e-commerce site ). on that filter I am loading the data in different different accordion tab on the basis of category. if I am removing that menu filter then the page is working fine. But I have to show that filter as well so that user can filter the main content.

Comment: I think I don't really understand why you need so much data for a filter. If there is no possibility for lazy loading, you can do some research on "angular performance" to find a way to speed it up.